# How to select planes on image having intersecting lines?

Tags: image, math, image-processing, geometry, lines

So I have a canvas of size `MxN` and lines defined by a set of two 2d points on that canvas which belong them `[(m1, n1), (m2, n2)...]`. How to devide canvas onto planes enclosed by such lines?

Example lines on image:
[image]

Lines are given by their end points.  We want t get planes formed by line intersections and would-be line intersections if lines were prolongated. You can imagine them covering walls and other plane surfaces.

Comment: Do you know how to find the intersection of two lines? Given three points on a line, do you know how to determine which one is between the other two? How do you want to describe the enclosed regions (e.g. an ordered list of corners)?

Comment: A picture tells a thousand words. Show an example image of input (_"canvas with lines"_) and show an expected output (_"planes enclosed by such lines"_). Explain _"How to devide canvas"_ Are we talking rectangle blocks? Or maybe you mean like a [**boolean operation**](https://www.bram.us/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Screen-Shot-2011-12-06-at-14.32.59.png) on the intersections?

Comment: @VC.One: Added image and deails

Comment: You cannot robustly select lines belonging to the same plane, having only image without information about deep

Comment: I need only the planes formed by closest lines to each other, and I would like to add image border lines so that all image would be covered

Comment: I whish you good luck. On this sample, there are more false positives and false negatives than good stuff. It is actually unusable.